# Is there any way i can remove line breaks (not paragraph breaks) from a word document quickly?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word-2007, autohotkey

Is there any way i can remove line breaks (not paragraph breaks) from a word document quickly? Can we do in one shot using Autohotkey?
i have a large document in columns like this:

```
xxxxx x xxxx
xxx xxxx xx
xxxxxx x xxx
x xx xxxxxxx
xx xxxxx xxx

xxxxx x xxxx
xxx xxxx xx
xxxxxx x xxx
x xx xxxxxxx
xx xxxxx xxx

xxxxx x xxxx
xxx xxxx xx
xxxxxx x xxx
x xx xxxxxxx
xx xxxxx xxx
```

and i need to remove the line breaks so it's like this

```
xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx

xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx

xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace All `^p^p` with `<p>`*
2. Replace All `^p` with nothing
3. Replace All `<p>` with `^p`

(`^p` means a carriage return to Word's Find and Replace (it calls it a paragraph break))

* you can use any distinctive string to temporarily change paragraph breaks to; I chose the HTML paragraph string because it's mnemonic.